# Invoke an extension method on a method without a explicit reference

Tags: c#, methods, extension-methods

**Is there any way to invoke an extension method on a method, but without a explicit reference?**

For example, if I have a extension method:

```cs
public static class Extensions {
    public static void FooOn(this Func<string> method) =>
        Console.WriteLine($"Foo on {method()}");
}
```

I thought maybe I could do something like this, but perhaps not.

```cs
class Program {
    private string Bar() => "you"; 
    void Main() => Bar.FooOn();  // won't compile
}
```

Instead it seems I have to declare a temporary reference:

```cs
class Program {
    private string Bar() => "you"; 
    void Main(){
        Func<string> temp = Bar;
        temp.FooOn();
    }
}
```

So is there any way to invoke an extension method on a method, but without a explicit reference?

Comment: Changing the "bar" method to a property of type "func<string>" should do the trick

Comment: I must ask,  why would you want to extend a method?

Comment: Extension methods are available on implicit conversions if an identity, reference, or boxing conversion exists. Method group to delegate conversions likely do not satisfy this requirement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you can't, as it is a method, which cannot be used with extension methods.

There are several workarounds ([.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/e1urE7)):

1. As already mentioned in the question, you can create a temporary variable, which references the method:

   ```
   Func<string> temp = Bar;
   temp.FooOn();
   ```
2. You can explicitly cast `Bar` to a `Func<string>`:

   ```
   static void Main() => ((Func<string>)Bar).FooOn();
   ```
3. You call the extension method directly, passing `Bar` as a parameter:

   ```
   static void Main() => Extensions.FooOn(Bar);
   ```
4. You store `Bar` as a `Func<string>` variable:

   ```
   static Func<string> Bar = () => "you"; 
   static void Main() => Bar.FooOn();
   ```